Restricting type to extend object in TypeScript doesn't work - string is accepted
I am trying to enforce typing for an attributes object that's contained in a wrapper class. The reason behind this is to have proper typing when setting or getting individual attributes (getOne/setOne methods in the code below).
However, it doesn't seem to work properly - string is happily accepted as a parameter for AttributeCollection constructor which is wrong for the class's intended purpose:
type AttributeMap<M extends object> = {
  [key in keyof M]: M[key];
};

export class AttributeCollection<M extends object> {
  constructor(private attributes: AttributeMap<M>) {}

  public getOne<K extends keyof AttributeMap<M>>(key: K): M[K] {
    return this.attributes[key];
  }

  public setOne<K extends keyof AttributeMap<M>>(key: K, value: M[K]): void {
    this.attributes[key] = value;
  }
}

const acCorrectImplicit = new AttributeCollection({ a: 'str'}); // ok
const acCorrectExplicit = new AttributeCollection<{ a: string }>({ a: 'str'}); // ok

const acWrong = new AttributeCollection('str'); // ok, but shouldn't be

/*

The typing we get:

const acWrong: AttributeCollection<{
    toString: () => string;
    charAt: (pos: number) => string;
    charCodeAt: (index: number) => number;
    concat: (...strings: string[]) => string;
    indexOf: (searchString: string, position?: number | undefined) => number;
    ... 37 more ...;
    [Symbol.iterator]: () => IterableIterator<...>;
}>

*/

const am: AttributeMap<'str'> = 'str'; // error

console.log(acCorrectImplicit, acCorrectExplicit, acWrong, am);

I am probably passing types incorrectly somewhere - can you help me figure out what's wrong?
Here is the playground.

• What's the point of AttributeMap here? It looks like a no-op and you would just write  constructor(private attributes: M){} instead. What's the use case that motivates this? • It looks like string essentially gets widened to String (or the equivalent) which is not seen as a primitive. You could change to this version if you want to guarantee that the output is also a non-primitive. But are you looking for a workaround, or an explanation of the unexpected behavior? (and if "both", which one is more important?)

@jcalz, I actually removed the methods where I used the type for brevity. I wanted to be able to get/set single attributes like this: public setOne<K extends keyof AttributeMap<M>>(key: K, value: M[K]): void { this.attributes[key] = value; }. That was basically the main intention. And as a bonus wanted to understand what's going on here. Here is the code: https://tsplay.dev/mA0q1N

But you can just write public setOne<K extends keyof M>(key: K, value: M[K]): void { this.attributes[key] = value; }. There doesn't seem to be any point to AttributeMap. If its  definition is truly just {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}, that's a fancy way of writing T, for most purposes. So again, what's the use case that motivates it?

You are right @jcalz - I will update my question to make it clearer what I wanted to achieve and you might provide an answer that I'll accept. I was trying to make typings correct for the individual attributes and this kind of extra type seemed to do the task. But your suggestion will work much better and be more clear.

It looks like the mapped type AttributeMap<M> causes the inferred type argument to widen from string (a primitive) to the String interface (the wrapper object type) and it isn't rejected. This may or may not be a bug in TypeScript; I couldn't easily find an existing issue.
If you really care about ensuring that the output of AttributeMap is also compatible with the object type, you can intersect with object:
type AttributeMap<M extends object> = object & {
  [K in keyof M]: M[K];
};

Then everything works as desired:
const acCorrectImplicit = new AttributeCollection({ a: 'str' }); // ok
const acCorrectExplicit = new AttributeCollection<{ a: string }>({ a: 'str' }); // ok
const acWrong = new AttributeCollection("str"); // error


Of course, for the example as given, there is no obvious reason to use AttributeMap at all. It's essentially the identity function for types. So AttributeMap<M> is more or less equivalent to M. And if you just directly use M, then your problem also goes away:
export class AttributeCollection<M extends object> {
  constructor(private attributes: M) { }

  public getAttributes(): M {
    return this.attributes;
  }
}

const acCorrectImplicit = new AttributeCollection({ a: 'str' }); // ok
const acCorrectExplicit = new AttributeCollection<{ a: string }>({ a: 'str' }); // ok
const acWrong = new AttributeCollection("str"); // error

Playground link to code

I've updated the code to include getOne/setOne methods used to manipulate individual attributes and they work perfectly when I replace AttributeMap<M> to just M.

AttributeMap feels redundant.  I feel like a simpler type would be what you want here..
export class AttributeCollection<M extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  constructor(private attributes: M) {}

  public getOne<K extends keyof M>(key: K): M[K] {
    return this.attributes[key];
  }

  public setOne<K extends keyof M>(key: K, value: M[K]): void {
    this.attributes[key] = value;
  }
}



Solution:
Use NoInfer<M> to forbid TS from infering the primitive methods as object:
export class AttributeCollection<M extends object> {
  constructor(private attributes: AttributeMap<NoInfer<M>>) {}

  public getAttributes(): AttributeMap<NoInfer<M>> {
    return this.attributes;
  }
}

Note: This requires typescript@^5.4.
const acWrong = new AttributeCollection("string"); // error as expected

Playground
It seems like a bug in TypeScript that infers primitive methods as object rather than the actual type.

I wouldn't do this; this blocks inference entirely. acCorrectImplicit is not the right type anymore, for example.
